# Use MPI_Send and MPI_Recv between Parent and Child process created with MPI_Comm_spawn

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to use MPI_Send() and MPI_Recv() to communicate between a child and its parent process, created by using MPI_Comm_spawn as can be seen below:

Parent.f90

```
program master
use mpi
implicit none

    integer :: ierr, num_procs, my_id, intercomm, i, array(10), tag

    CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)

    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

    if (.not. (ierr .eq. 0)) then
        print*, "S.Unable to initilaize!"
        stop
    endif

    if (my_id .eq. 0) then
        call MPI_Comm_spawn("./child.out", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, my_id, &
        & MPI_COMM_WORLD, intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE, ierr)

        call MPI_Send(array, 255, MPI_INTEGER, my_id, tag, intercomm, ierr)
    endif

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program master
```

Child.f90

```
program name
use mpi
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer :: ierr, parent, my_id, n_procs, i, array(10), tag, intercomm
    logical :: flag, high

    ! executable statements
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Initialized(flag, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_get_parent(parent, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_procs, ierr)

    print *, "Initilaized? ", flag
    print *, "My mommy is: ", parent
    print *, "My rank is:", my_id

    tag = 1

    call MPI_Recv(array, 255, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, tag, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)
    print *, "Client received array."

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program name
```

When the above program is run, the Parent seem to run through fine, but the Child never prints: "Client received array.", leading me to believe that I have messed something up with the send/recv.

If it is not clear what I am trying to achieve, I want the parent to spawn a child, send an array to that child, *the child to process the array and the child to send the array back to the parent*. (italics is yet to be written, I want to get this basic communication working first)

At the moment, when I run: `mpiexec -np 1 parent.out`, the child prints:

```
Initilaized?  T
My mommy is:            3
My rank is:           0
```

but not "Client received array."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue. The following code starts a parent, sends an array of size 1000000 to its child, the child squares the array and sends it back to its parent.

Parent.f90

```
program master
use mpi
implicit none

    integer :: ierr, num_procs, my_id, intercomm, i, array(1000000), s_tag, s_dest, siffra

    CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)

    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)

    !print *, "S.Rank =", my_id
    !print *, "S.Size =", num_procs

    if (.not. (ierr .eq. 0)) then
        print*, "S.Unable to initilaize bös!"
        stop
    endif

    do i=1,size(array)
        array(i) = 2
    enddo

    if (my_id .eq. 0) then
        call MPI_Comm_spawn("./client2.out", MPI_ARGV_NULL, 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, my_id, &
        & MPI_COMM_WORLD, intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE, ierr)


        s_dest = 0 !rank of destination (integer)
        s_tag =  1 !message tag (integer)
        call MPI_Send(array(1), 1000000, MPI_INTEGER, s_dest, s_tag, intercomm, ierr)

        call MPI_Recv(array(1), 1000000, MPI_INTEGER, s_dest, s_tag, intercomm, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

        !do i=1,10
        !   print *, "S.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
        !enddo

    endif

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

end program master
```

Child.f90

```
program name
use mpi
implicit none

    ! type declaration statements
    integer :: ierr, parent, my_id, n_procs, i, array(1000000), ctag, csource, intercomm, siffra
    logical :: flag

    ! executable statements
    call MPI_Init(ierr)
    call MPI_Initialized(flag, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_get_parent(parent, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, n_procs, ierr)

    csource = 0 !rank of source
    ctag = 1 !message tag

    call MPI_Recv(array(1), 1000000, MPI_INTEGER, csource, ctag, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr)

    !do i=1,10
    !    print *, "C.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
    !enddo

    do i=1,size(array)
        array(i) = array(i)**2
    enddo

    !do i=1,10
    !    print *, "C.Array(",i,"): ", array(i)
    !enddo

    call MPI_Send(array(1), 1000000, MPI_INTEGER, csource, ctag, parent, ierr)

    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
end program name
```